# How to use subscription products in WooCommerce Subscriptions REST-API?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

We have a product configured as simple subscription product.

If you buy that product on the shop site directly, it will automatically create a subscription for this order after purchase.

We want to achieve the same behaviour with a REST-API call.

We know there is a [create subscription endpoint](https://woocommerce.github.io/subscriptions-rest-api-docs/?ruby#create-a-subscription) but we explicitly don't want to use this.
We want the same way like on the page.

So we tried to use the [create a order endpoint](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order) and added the product as line_Item (using ruby code here):

```rb
data = { customer_id: 1, currency: 'EUR', line_items: [{product_id: 1, quantity: 1}] }
response = woocommmerce.post('orders', data).parsed_response

puts response

{"id"=>532,
 "parent_id"=>0,
 "status"=>"pending",
 "currency"=>"EUR",
 "version"=>"6.9.4",
 "prices_include_tax"=>true,
 "date_created"=>"2022-10-10T14:34:11",
 "date_modified"=>"2022-10-10T14:34:11",
 "discount_total"=>"0.00",
 "discount_tax"=>"0.00",
 "shipping_total"=>"0.00",
 "shipping_tax"=>"0.00",
 "cart_tax"=>"0.00",
 "total"=>"1.00",
 "total_tax"=>"0.00",
 "customer_id"=>1,
 "order_key"=>"wc_order_xxx",
 "billing"=> ...,
 "shipping"=>...,
 "payment_method"=>"",
 "payment_method_title"=>"",
 "transaction_id"=>"",
 "customer_ip_address"=>"",
 "customer_user_agent"=>"",
 "created_via"=>"rest-api",
 "customer_note"=>"",
 "date_completed"=>nil,
 "date_paid"=>nil,
 "cart_hash"=>"",
 "number"=>"532",
 "meta_data"=>[{"id"=>9854, "key"=>"_gzd_version", "value"=>"3.10.6"}],
 "line_items"=>
   [{"id"=>23,
     "name"=>"Abo (3 Months)",
     "product_id"=>1,
     "variation_id"=>0,
     "quantity"=>1,
     "tax_class"=>"19-mwst",
     "subtotal"=>"1.00",
     "subtotal_tax"=>"0.00",
     "total"=>"1.00",
     "total_tax"=>"0.00",
     "taxes"=>[],
     "meta_data"=>...,
     "sku"=>"",
     "price"=>1,
     "image"=>{"id"=>"187", "src"=>"placeholder.png"},
     "parent_name"=>nil}],
 "tax_lines"=>[],
 "shipping_lines"=>[],
 "fee_lines"=>[],
 "coupon_lines"=>[],
 "refunds"=>[],
 "payment_url"=>"https://test.de/kasse/order-pay/532/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_xxx&force_pay_order=1",
 "is_editable"=>true,
 "needs_payment"=>true,
 "needs_processing"=>true,
 "date_created_gmt"=>"2022-10-10T14:34:11",
 "date_modified_gmt"=>"2022-10-10T14:34:11",
 "date_completed_gmt"=>nil,
 "date_paid_gmt"=>nil,
 "shipments"=>[],
 "shipping_status"=>"no-shipping-needed",
 "currency_symbol"=>"€",
 "parcel_delivery_opted_in"=>"",
 "direct_debit"=>{"holder"=>"", "iban"=>"", "bic"=>"", "mandate_id"=>""},
 "_links"=>...
}
```

That looks fine.

In our current flow we will open the payment_url from above and complete the checkout.
That also works fine.

But it **does not** create a subscription, like it does on the shop page.

What am I missing here?
Is this process possible with REST-API calls?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
spa